# Error :Use of undeclared type 'NSObject' in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I build a new Data structure called "CheckItem"(I am doing a Todo project)

and I let CheckItem class inherit the `NSObject` and `NSCoding`

But Xcode alert the compile-time error at line 1:

```
class CheckItem : NSObject,NSCoding {
```

> the hint is : **Use of undeclared type 'NSObject'(and 'NSCoding')**

The whole class as follow:

```
 class CheckItem : NSObject,NSCoding {
        var text: String
        var isDone :Bool
        var imageName :String
        init(text: String,isDone: Bool,imageName: String){
            self.text = text
            self.isDone = isDone
            self.imageName = imageName
        }
        init(text: String,isDone: Bool){
            self.text = text
            self.isDone = isDone
            self.imageName = "No Icon"
        }

}
```

Can you point my error? Thank you very much!

Comment: You forgot to `import Foundation`.

Comment: @mixel Thanks! It works! I thought that every class will import Foundation automatically

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put following statement top in your class:

```
import Foundation
```

Even after that you would need to implement following methods to be able to compile. This is because you are implementing `NSCoding` protocol so your class must conform to it by implementing these:

```
public func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder)
public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

Comment: ok cool. Could you please accept this answer for the benefit of others.

Comment: `import Foundation`, Didn't resolve `Use of undeclared type 'NSObject'` for macOS